# jQuery : 2 fadeIn calls after each other not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, fadein

I am developping a PhoneGap/JQueryMobile app. I have a container div containing another div with an image and a text (both divs have the "display:none;" css property at the beginning of the animation). I would like to fade in the container and then fade in the div that is inside.
Here is the code :

```
$(".container").fadeIn(350, function(){
    $(".innnerDiv").fadeIn(350);
});
```

This works fine on computer browsers, iPad but not on iPhone. The container fades properly but the inner div just shows at the end of the animation.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: My guess is that the iPhone can't handle the operation because of RAM or resouces available. Your code is perfectly valid. You coooould try to increase the duration and see if that works.

Comment: Looks like you were right. I tried rebooting the iPhone and it worked fine. I will have to remember not to put too many of those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from my experience i would add that you should always add a `.stop(true, true)` before an animation call (no matter whether it is fade, slide, animate ...).

It can produce weird results and even freeze your app if an animation isn't stopped and removed from the queue before another one starts.